# Exception 16 is thrown during Preview Rendering of XML file and one string throws error "is translated here but not in default locale"

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, render

I have the following XML file:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="com.ad123.oshikwanyamadictionary.EditorActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="7dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="term in question"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingStart="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/term_in_question"/>
        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:hint="@string/translation_suggestion"
            android:id="@+id/suggestion_edit_text"
            />
        <Spinner
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingStart="3dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:id="@+id/language_report_spinner">
        </Spinner>
        <!--android:entries="@array/sourceLanguage"
            android:entries="@array/wordType"-->
        <Spinner
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingStart="3dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/word_type_spinner"
            android:visibility="gone">
        </Spinner>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:id="@+id/term_plural_edit_text"
            android:hint="@string/plural_of_term_contribution"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/translation_plural_edit_text"
            android:hint="@string/plural_of_translation_contribution"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/term_example_edit_text"
            android:hint="@string/example_using_term_contribution"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/translation_example_edit_text"
            android:hint="@string/example_using_translation_contrinution"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/alternative"
            android:hint="@string/alternative_edit_text"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/send_data"
            android:text="@string/send_data"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/Button"/>
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar_edit"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/or_edit_choose"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now if I try to preview it, it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16
    at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:854)
    at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:603)
    at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:50)
    at android.text.StaticLayout$Builder.build(StaticLayout.java:425)
    at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:8272)
    at android.widget.TextView.assumeLayout(TextView.java:8104)
    at android.widget.TextView.onPreDraw(TextView.java:6742)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:977)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.dispatchOnPreDraw(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:46)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:404)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:543)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:426)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.render(BridgeRenderSession.java:108)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:154)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:136)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$renderInner$5(RenderTask.java:671)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have already tried to clean the project and also change the target api of the preview, but nothing seems to help. At the same time I get an error for only one string. It is the string used in the last TextView: @String/or_edit_choose. Although it is translated to all languages, it still gives me the error message: "or_edit_choose is translated here but not in default locale". The thing is, that the error message is shown to me in the default strings.xml file, which should be the default locale. I do not know if the errors are connected, but they both showed up at the same time. There was also a brief moment, where the string could be accessed from another layout file, just not from the one given above. Now it cannot be accessed from any file.

Comment: instead of
 
tools:text="term in question"  write

 android:text="term in question"

Comment: That didn't have any effect on the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **strings.xml** add this line

`tools:ignore="ExtraTranslation" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

to `<resources>` tag

like this

```
<resources tools:ignore="ExtraTranslation" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, although that only solved the second problem. But thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the tag android:visibility="gone" caused the rendering to be impossible. After I changed it to visible in the xml, to change it in the java file to the values needed, the rendering worked without a problem. I have no idea though, why this might be affecting the rendering.